# Understanding Healpy's getformat function

Tags: fits, healpy

I have a FITS file of a CMB full-sky map, with T, Q, U values.

Using the function healpy.fitsfunc.getformat(t), the output is the "FITS convention format string of data type t".

For my FITS file, I get "A29". Is this a standardized FITS convention?

Comment: Please paste your code. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I don't understand the question, but "A29" means that this column in the table is strings of length 29 characters.